# Is it possible to infer the type of component properties based on parent component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have this container

```
export interface State {
  email: string
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: State) => ({
  email: state.email,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => ({
  onChange: (name: string, value: string) => dispatch(/*...*/),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

and this component

```
export interface LoginProps {
  email: string
  onChange: (name: string, value: string) => void
}

const Login = (props: LoginProps) => (
  <p>Render something here</p>
)
```

Is there a way to infer the type of the login properties based on the `Container` definition so I don't have to manually define `LoginProps` ?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you would like the code to look?

Comment: Ideally I want to be able to specify nothing, just infer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good type definitions for `connect`, so the types of the props passed to the wrapped component can be inferred.  If you wrote the container/component like this...

```
export interface State {
  email: string
}

const stateToProps = (state: State) => ({
    email: state.email
  })

const dispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<Action>) => ({
    onChange: (name: string, value: string) => dispatch(/*...*/)
})

const BlahBlah = connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(({ email, onChange }) => (
    <div />
));
```

`email` and `onChange` are typed correctly without additional annotation.

However, when you write the `Login` component separately, without type annotation...

```
const Login = (props) => (
  <p>Render something here</p>
)
```

the type of `props` cannot be inferred.  This is because in addition to passing `Login` to `connect`, you could also call it directly.  For example, I could write in a component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Login unrelated="a string" typescript="cool" />
    );
}
```

Without annotation on the Login component, there is no way for the compiler to know which of the invocations of `Login` (the connected one, or my direct rendering) provides the correct props.  Without annotation then the compiler can only type props as `any`, so we lose type-safety.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes total sense